# How do I execute a PHP function every two seconds inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this PHP function called `GetTotalItemsPercentage()` which gets the amount of entries in my MySQL database and returns a percent based on the maximum amount of entries that are allowed (returns 50, 40, 39 etc.). However, I want this to update a div's height depending on this percentage. I currently have this code, however after the first update, it doesn't update again.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#filled-jackpot-display").animate({height:'<?php include 'database/config.php'; include 'database/jackpot.php'; echo getPotFilledPercentage(); ?>%'});
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

So how would I go about getting it to update every two seconds and constantly change the size of the div? I'm guessing I will have to run a loop in the PHP code and then use echo inside the PHP file to run JavaScript rather than the other way.

Comment: Use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP executes on server, javaScript on the client, you have to make a new php file with

```
<?php include 'database/config.php'; include 'database/jackpot.php'; echo getPotFilledPercentage(); ?>
```

in it, let's call it 'getTotalIP.php' then you call it with ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval($.ajax('getTotalIP'), 2000); //Short answer with jQuery
</script>
```

If your script is intended to print something then you need more code to parse the answer. A good way to do it is printing the php result in json and parse it with javaScript.

Here you have more cross-browswer ajax information: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute `PHP` on the client side. The way to do this would be to call the php code with [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then `animate` in the **success** handler

**myscipt.php**

```
<?php include 'database/config.php'; include 'database/jackpot.php'; echo getPotFilledPercentage(); ?>
```

**myscript.js**

```
setInterval( function() { 
    $.ajax({url: 'myscript.php', success: function(data){
       $("#filled-jackpot-display").animate({height: data});
}, 2000);
```

Note, since ajax is *asynchronous*, it may not *smoothly* `animate` in 2 second intervals. If you only need the height once, then `load` it on `ready` and proceed to animate in 2 second intervals